# How to enable copy-paste texts between host MacOS and VMware Fusion MacOS?

Tags: mac, vmware-fusion

My main OS is Big Sur and I also Mojave on VMware fusion to run certain applications. Copy-paste and file sharing between host and guest systems are enabled in VM settings, but not working. Is there any other setting I have to work on to fix this?

Comment: Did you, or can you, install or re-install the VMware Tools on the guest system?  You need Tools installed to enable copy / paste between guest and host.

Comment: I didn't actually. I also run Ubuntu and didn't have to install anything for that.

Comment: Ubuntu would normally install Tools automatically. So they are probably installed in Ubuntu (that is true for my Ubuntu Guest).

Comment: It worked after installing the tools. Thank you.

Comment: I posted a proper answer for you and for others. Perhaps you could acknowledge the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable copy / paste from Guest machine to Host machine or the other way, you need to install VMware Tools on the Guest Machine.

For a MAC Mojave Guest, here are the VMware Tools instructions.

[Install VMware Tools on Mojave](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1032440)

> Power on the virtual machine and log in.
>
> From the Apple menu, go to Virtual Machine > Install VMware Tools.
>
> Click Install when prompted.
>
> The VMware Tools volume mounts and opens automatically.
>
> Double-click Install VMware Tools.
>
> Click Continue to initiate the installation process.
>
> Click Install to agree to install VMware Tools on the boot volume.
>
> Click Continue Installation to agree to install now.
>
> Enter your administrator password to allow the installation, then
> click Install Software.
>
> Click Restart.